# Best approach to download the data and store that into Sqlite. Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, background-process

My requirement is whenever server push some data that should be received and stored into sqlite DB whether the app is in background or foreground. I am using Xamarin.forms and it should work on all three platforms Android, iOS and UWP.
is it possible through Push Notification or Web Sockets?

Comment: It depends on the data size of the message you send to your clients... For android & iOS, PushNotifications payload max size is about about 4K. If it's bigger, I suggest you to implement a "synch" process triggered by your clients (via webservices for instance)... Web sockets are mostly used for full duplex communications, so I presume you don't need to use it...

Comment: yeah data size is more than 4k ....So you mean client should trigger a background task as soon as client receive notification from the server to pull the data...

Comment: Yes it could be a good solution. Else if you don't want to implement background tasks, maybe you can wait for your user to open the app and start 'a background process (thread)' to pull data if needed...

Answer (score 0):

`Push Notifications` - should be the right way to go. Simply because they can awake your application even if it is killed by the OS. With `WebSockets` there is no way to achieve that and ensure that your applications will always receive a remote message.

One remark, I am not sure about the UWP part, I would suggest to check the existing threads on SO in this specific case.